# Typedef in C# across several source files

Tags: c#

I am writing a C wrapper an would like to use a typedef aquivalent to define some types which should be valid in quite a lot of source files. Those "types" are just different aliases to [u]int16/32/64_t, but are useful to distinguish function parameters.

One could use `using MyId=System.Int32;`, but this needs to be redeclared in every file as far as I see... Is there a better way?

Comment: Couldn't you just use Int16,Int32,Int64 or short, int, long directly?

Comment: Is this really good practive to typedef in C?  Does it not make the code harder to read?

Comment: This is theoretically possible, but those type names carry information in the function declarations ...

Comment: @drelihan: It's not my choice and not changeable for this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternate approach is to use a struct with implicit conversion to the underlying type.

```
public struct MyHandle
{
    private int _handle;

    internal MyHandle(int handle)
    {
        _handle = handle;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(MyHandle handle)
    {
        return handle._handle;
    }
}
```

Your internal code can still use it as the underlying type (int in this case) via the implicit conversion, but you expose it as a strong type to the user.  Your user can also see the int value, though it's effectively meaningless to them.  They can't directly cast an int to your Handle type, as the constructor is internal to your assembly and you don't provide a conversion operator for the other direction.

Comment: I gave you a vote up because this is a nice little step into parts of C# that aren't often seen. It's also a clever solution. But I'd have a hard time actually accepting and using this solution in real code.

Comment: I've used a similar approach for mathematical code (concrete to a specific application) that had to operate with different coordinate systems.  It was extremely helpful for me to be able to see from the function definitions what coordinate systems were being used, even though the underlying data structure was essentially a 3d Vector in every case.  It allowed for clean overloading solutions where the correct change of basis function is used, depending on the coordinate systems involved.

Comment: I read somewhere that the MS JIT can emit code that deals with structs like this almost as fast as dealing with the underlying "int" itself - e.g. it can store the handle in a register.

Comment: Sadly this does not work with `ref`/`out`. So `void foo(int* a)` in C can not be translated to `static extern void foo(ref MyHandle a)` in C#.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you do this: `foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref MyHandle a)`?

Comment: @Dan: Ok, I was wrong. `static extern void foo(ref MyHandle a)` works, using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]` also works. What does not work is calling a `void foo(ref int a)` with `MyHandle h = ...; foo(ref h)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm assuming that you want to distinguish between a legitimate use of say UInt32 and your custom type, yes you would need to manually reference your alias everywhere you want it to be used.